# Angular won't rerender to disable button after property change

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a button I want to deactivate when a slider reached its end.

```
<button class="ml-3 next-button position-relative" (click)="scrollRight()" [disabled]="!rightIsActive">
</button>

-----------------------------------------
@Input() set active(value) {
  this.checkDisabled(value);
}

rightIsActive = true;

checkDisabled(value) {
    this.rightIsActive = value !== this.length - 1;
}
```

The function is working properly - logging `rightIsActive`, after the slider has reached its end, its value is `false`. Somehow though, **Angular won't rerender and actually disable the button.** How so?

Comment: Where/how are you calling `checkDisabled` exactly?

Comment: Can you please share the code triggering `rightIsActive` and also the slider code.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Please see edit!

Comment: @KishorKunal Please see edit!

Comment: And where does `length` come from? Are you checking `length` of `value` which is a `string`? Please use something like https://stackblitz.com/ to create an example to troubleshoot.

Comment: There might be the case your application's change detection is not working properly and you have to forcefully check for change detection whenever there is change in the variable

Comment: Or you need to use `ngOnChanges` to handle changes. Either way, please create a working example and update the question to show what/where/how `length` in statements like `this.length` is created.

Comment: Can you post an image of your view, want to see how it looks?

Comment: How and where is `active` input property being used? Because that is where you are expecting the `checkDisabled` getting called and changing the `rightIsActive`.